# how can I have eclipse auto insert subversion revision number into my code

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm interested in displaying the version number of my code in a help page. Ideally I'd use a Major.Minor.SVNrevision format, where the SVNrevision number was pulled automatically. I hope? Suspect there's a variable I can access somewhere, but have no idea what it may be.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding so-called SVN Keywords into your working files. [This chapter contains standard SVN keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.4). Then you have two options:

1. set property for each folder **svn:keywords** to make this substitution available for all who works with this repository: **svn propset svn:keywords "Date Author Revision" help.html**
2. modify svn configuration file (on Windows: *%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\config*, on Linux: *~/.subversion/config*) to enable automatic properties for all repositories and files (according to pattern)  you're working with: set **enable-auto-props** to **yes** and then add to [auto-props] section: ***.html = svn:keywords=Date Author Revision**

Comment: Can I put latest revison number of directorz into some file? I'd liek have a file with latest trunk revision - how to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you can, if you look at the link in my answer: you need to have 1. add to some file keyword $Rev$ and 2. set property for this file: svn ps svn:keywords "Rev" file. Then, after each svn update, $Rev$ will be replaced with the latest revision. HTH

Comment: I still can't find it - I want to have revision number of file A in file B. How do I do that?

Comment: This is not possible directly, you can for example post-process keywords in files of interest manually - e.g. with some script to update your file with versions, and then you can go further and with the help of post-commit hooks make this file to be updated automatically, actually, this goes out of svn, however don't know - maybe some plugin exists for eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If your help files are versioned, I would add an external script as an Eclipse builder in order to make some keyword substitution ([using for instance `svnversion`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html))

But if your help files are generated, may be this [kind of script can help](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#version-value-in-source) (also based on `svnversion` to get back the "`GlobalRev`").

Major and Minor version information need to be stored and retrieved from another souce though: they are not "svn-related" informations.