# How do I define @since tags in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

How can I define text appearing after `@since` tag in Javadoc generated by Eclipse for new classes?

Comment: Are you asking how to make Eclipse automatically insert the @since tag when it generates javadoc comments? It looks like this but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not exactly. Eclipse already inserts @since tag with some text after it, and the question is: how to define this text, in other words how to define version that Eclipse adds automatically to the class javadoc?

Comment: You may find some clues in [this question on inserting svn version in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518843/how-can-i-have-eclipse-auto-insert-subversion-revision-number-into-my-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse take a look at:

Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates

Comment: Not what I needed, unfortunately. There is no version configuration in this dialog. Maybe different version? I use Helios (3.6).

Comment: I'm using Helios 3.5.2. If I understand, you have to edit Code->Class Body adding tag @since + <your_comment>, isn't it?

Comment: OK, thanks, it did not worked only because project properties was different.

Answer (score 4):

here?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Project properties were different, didn't think of looking at them.